# New to Access looking to create a single report from multiple sub-reports based on a single record

Tags: ms-access, report, record

I am new to Access and i'm trying to produce a PDF report for individual applications. There are five reports for each application and I would like to combine these five reports into one PDF for each application.

I tried creating a new report and adding the five other reports as sub-reports; however, when I exported the new report as a PDF, I ended up getting information for every record in the database per each sub-report before moving onto the next application section (i.e., sub-report).

Any suggestions on how to get my combined report to return a single record so I can distinguish five separate applications?

Thanks,

Comment: Fix your queries?

Comment: I don't have any queries set up right now, but i'll look into that as a route to get this accomplished. Each sub-report is drawing from a table where all the data is stored.

Comment: Yeah, each sub-report should be looking at a query that filters the data and only shows what you want it to show.  You can even set them on report load, like: MyReport.RecordSet = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate > #1/1/2017#".  And you can use variables to change the recordsets too.